# Should I flag users that want to help but asking to remote control the PC, something like using AnyDesk, TeamViewer, or any?

Tags: discussion, flags, comments, comment-flags

I want to know if it is appropriate to ask somebody to use AnyDesk to try to resolve a problem in Stack Overflow programming question, something like this:

> [oh ok, do u have anydesk ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tTpT.png)

I know he/she maybe have good intentions to help, but using that app can risk other person's personal privacy being leaked, so should I flag it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, you can flag these comments as "no longer needed". That type of flag does not imply any ill intent or have any penalties associated with it.

In most cases, flagging the comments and getting a mod to delete them is enough for the user to realize that such requests are not welcome here. Assuming you think that they're asking in good faith, it would also be reasonable for you to reply (once), telling them that it is not appropriate to request off-site contact here, that we require all information to be included in the question and/or answers. If a reasonable attempt fails, the user continues to harass you, and/or you assume bad faith from the beginning, then you should raise a moderator flag asking for us to handle it. That should be done by flagging the *post* (either a question or an answer, it doesn't matter which one), choosing the "in need of moderator intervention" option, and typing a detailed explanation into the textbox provided.

Flags on a comment mean "this comment should be deleted". Generally speaking, that's all that will ever happen if you flag a comment. So, feel free to flag as "no longer needed" whenever you think the comment just needs to go away. If you want/need a moderator to take specific action, like contacting the user to explain site rules, then you should raise a custom flag on a post (not on a comment).

Comment: hey there, what about if the user said `Can I provide you further assistance with this? Do you want me to have a look at your project?` should I flag it? since the owner of the question not replying for 2 days already

Comment: @Stanly That example comment adds no information or other useful content. It is exactly the type of comment that should be flagged as "no longer needed". This is not a help desk; comments should not be left inquiring if there is anything else that someone needs help with.